# UINavigation Bar white blotch appearance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

This is a problem i am getting every now and then, but can't find anything about it anywhere the navigation bar has a white circle or blotch on top left side of my app i have added the image as background image in uinavigationbar appearence in app delegate.

Please help me out of this thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: have u used MPVolumeView anywhere in your project??

Comment: Yes i have used it to hide the default display of volume bar in ios

Comment: worked?? thats great :) Please share what u did so that others can get help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the MPVolumeView, or change its properties to remove the blotch.